# How can I add labels to the single bars?

Tags: r, bar-chart

[image]

```
table(Location)
barplot(table(Location), 
        ylim = c(0,500),
        names.arg = c("Immunology check", "Pool-Box", "Sample box", "Sample box immunology", "Trash"),
        xlab = "Box", 
        ylab = "Count",
        main = "Location of the samples", 
        col= rainbow(5),
        )
```

Comment: add a location data

Comment: Sorry I'm new, what do you mean?

Comment: table(Location), we need it

Comment: https://github.com/michelepons/STACKQUESTION.git     This is the link of the data, don't think it was what you meant but it should work.

Comment: How do you read csv file? ```Location <- read.csv("Location.csv", header = T, sep = ",")``` Am I right?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: Now  I understand you) When I return to home, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Location <- read.csv("Location.csv", header = T, sep = ",")

x <- barplot (table(Location), 
         ylim = c(0,500), xlim = c(0,6), names.arg = c("Immunology \n check", "Pool-Box", "Sample box", "Sample \n box immunology", "Trash"), 
         xlab = "Box", ylab = "Count", main = "Location of the samples", cex.names = 0.8, col = "red", border = NA)
```

[image]

For the future projects try to use ggplot2, it has more advantages.